# How to set up a margin for navbar icon?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-animation, android-bottomnav

I am using BottomNavigationview and I want to animate the height of it, so it is extendable. My problem is that the Items stay centered vertically, but they should have a fix top-margin of e.g. 5dp. How is it possible to move them up with the top of the navbar?

My XML for one of five Items (with text!) (in menu folder):

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/testid1"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_test1"
    android:title="@string/Overview"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    />
```

The XML for the Navbar:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    app:itemIconSize="26dp"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/NavBarGrey"
    app:itemRippleColor="#B5F1F1F1"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/NavBarGrey"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

Here the Kotlin-Code for the "up" animation:

```
val anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(convertDpToPixel(56.0).toInt(), convertDpToPixel(400.0).toInt())
anim.addUpdateListener { valueAnimator ->
    val `val` = valueAnimator.animatedValue as Int
        val layoutParams: ViewGroup.LayoutParams =
                bottom_navigation.getLayoutParams()
        layoutParams.height = `val`
        bottom_navigation.setLayoutParams(layoutParams)
}
anim.setInterpolator(OvershootInterpolator(1.0f))
anim.duration = 450
anim.start()
```

[Here is how it looks right now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3bXC.gif)

The round items should move up to the top like the blue button (which is an extra object and not part of the navbar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, just animated the padding...